# Error messages in importing data file

Tags: import

> I want to copy the data in a public file (link in code below) and put each row of the data as a sub-list, i.e., in the format
>
> ```
> {{Beginn,Ende,Dienst,ein/ausgehend,Laenge,Breite,Richtung,Cell-Id_A,Cell-Id_B,},{8/31/09 7:57,8/31/09 8:09,GPRS,ausgehend,13.39611111,52.52944444,30,45830,XXXXXXXXXX,},{....},..}
> ```
>
> I tried copying to *Mathematica* using the code
>
> ```
> Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=\0An0YnoiCbFHGdGp3WnJkbE4xWTdDTVV0ZDlQeWZmSXc&authkey=COCjw-kG&hl=en_\GB&authkey=COCjw-kG#gid=0"]
> ```
>
> but it gives me the following error message

```
RegularExpression::maxrec: Recursion limit exceeded; positive match might be missed. >>
```

> I tried the alternative by first saving the file as CDFdata.csv on my machine under and used the code
>
> ```
> Import["CDFdata.csv", Path -> "E:"]
> ```
>
> but I get this error message
>
> ```
> Import::nffil: File not found during Import. >>
> ```
>
> Can someone please provide guidance on how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: The URL appears to be wrong.

Comment: > I just checked this      https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0An0YnoiCbFHGdGp3WnJkbE4xWTdDTVV0ZDlQeWZmSXc&authkey=COCjw-kG&hl=en_GB&authkey=COCjw-kG#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

By importing that URL you are asking *Mathematica* to do something overly complex, since you are asking it to parse the page source code for the Google Docs interface. Even if *Mathematica* could process it, all you would have would be symbolic XML representing that HTML code, not the values that you want.

It should however work to import the data if you export it as CVS first. I did this, and it worked. So just make sure you have the filename all right, here is how I found the file on OS X (then name that was chosen by default started with VDS_MS):

```
Import[First@FileNames["VDS_MS" ~~ __, {"~/Downloads"}]]
```

`E:` is probably a drive on Windows or something, I'm not familiar with the syntax on that platform. But that's where your problem lies, so just work on finding the correct path to where the file is and it should work for you.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with _Mathematica_ reading non-_Mathematica_ files on my computer. I tried moving to another drive, e.g., `Import["VDS.csv", 
 Path -> "C:\\Documents and Settings\\IW\\My Documents\\Downloads"]` but failed. Does the failure of the following example (from _Mathematica 9.0_ Documentation on *Path*) `dir = $TemporaryPrefix;Put[47!, ToFileName[{dir}, "fact"]]` provide *a clue*? The error message was _OpenWrite::noopen: Cannot open C:\Documents and Settings\IW\Local Settings\Temp\m\fact. >>_

Comment: What happens if you do `SetDirectory["C:\\Documents and Settings\\IW\\My Documents\\Download"]` and then `FileNames[]`? If the path is right, you should see a list of files and VDS.csv amongst them. I'm not sure how to interpret the error you've given.

Comment: I tried 'SetDirectory["C:\\Documents and Settings\\IW\\My \
Documents\\Download"] ; FileNames[]` but got the error message _SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory to C:\Documents and Settings\IW\My Documents\Download. >>_ Per _Mathematica_ this means there is no such directory. Interestingly, it did output the list of folders under _My Documents_ folder including _Download_ as if it could only go so deep.

Comment: Well, but if you put the file in My Documents and you can see the file with FileNames[] then works when you try to import it without entering a path, just `Import[filel]`, right?

Comment: Thanks. That works. Also I noticed an extra .csv that may have been confusing the program as to the file type.