# Opening Mathematica file in Google drive

Tags: import, files-and-directories, web-access

I have a *Mathematica* file in my Google drive. There is no option to open the *Mathematica* file directly, without downloading it.

Is it possible to directly open the file from Google drive?

Answer (score 10):

If you have a public link, you can follow the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112437/10397), and basically just import the data

```
Import[url, "Data"]
```

If you need to authenticate to get a private link, then you will need [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147452/10397) and the packlet by @b3m2a1

```
PacletInstall[
  "ServiceConnection_GoogleDrive", 
  "Site" -> 
   "http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
  ];

gd = ServiceConnect["GoogleDrive"]
```

Comment: The OP seems to ask how to open the file with a web app — "without downloading it". And `Import` does download, I suppose (although you might not find the resulting file on your file system).

Comment: @Ruslan well something or another would get downloaded no matter what. Thats the way web works.

Comment: @joojaa I would not consider the same fetching a file and opening it in a dedicated web app directly from GD. The more that there is also a WolframCloud where you can work with notebooks without fetching them. My interpretation of the question was the same as Ruslan's, does not mean we are right though, let's wait for OP. p.s. I think the answer is no.

Comment: Anybody figured this one out?

Answer (score 9):

There is now [a Chrome app for opening Wolfram notebooks in Wolfram Cloud](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wolfram-cloud/pmmdlebjfpgaljkkeheoghmcpafbckig).

Once you've installed the app, you can visit your Google Drive on the web and double-click to open a notebook file.  You'll get something that looks like this...

[image]

Choose Wolfram Cloud.  If you've never done it before, you'll be prompted to log into Wolfram Cloud, and then asked to link your Google account to your Wolfram ID in a series of prompts including something like this...

[image]

Once you've navigated adding the various permissions, the notebook will open directly in Wolfram Cloud.  Even though it's opened in Wolfram Cloud, it'll be backed by Google Drive rather than by the storage in your Wolfram Cloud account.  In the toolbar, you'll see a button with a Google Drive icon (and the filename widget will also have the tooltip depicted here):

[image]

Note, though, that it's not strictly necessary to press the Save button.  The document will auto-save to your Drive account periodically.